# Cannot mock http.ServerResponse with Sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon

My method accepts an `http.ServerResponse` and calls some methods on it.  Looking at [Sinon's docs](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#mocks) it appears that this should be trivial.  however, I either get `TypeError: response.writeHead is not a function` if I don't set up an expectation or `TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property writeHead as function` if I do set one up.

```
var http = require('http'),
    sinon = require('sinon'),
    ServerResponse = http.ServerResponse;


function SendWelcomeResponse(response) {
    var body = 'Hello World!';

    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Content-Length': body.length});
    response.write(body);
    response.end();
}

describe('Using Sinon I should be able to mock the ServerResponse', function () {
    it.only('should mock correctly', function () {
        var mockServerResponse = sinon.mock(ServerResponse);
        mockServerResponse.expects('writeHead').once();
        SendWelcomeResponse(mockServerResponse);
    });
});
```

**Hand rolling an object to mock**

I've just tried the two suggestions below, these gives `TypeError: response.writeHead is not a function`.

```
var sinon = require('sinon'),
    stubServerResponse = {
        writeHead: function(statusCode, headers) {},
        write: function(body){},
        end: function() {}
    };


function SendWelcomeResponse(response) {
    var body = 'Hello World!';

    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Content-Length': body.length});
    response.write(body);
    response.end();
}

describe('Using Sinon I should be able to mock the ServerResponse', function () {
    it.only('should mock correctly', function () {
        var mockServerResponse = sinon.mock(stubServerResponse);
        mockServerResponse.expects('writeHead').once();
        SendWelcomeResponse(mockServerResponse);
    });
});
```

**Working!**

The magic was the solutions suggested below, and using the `.object` property of the mock object rather than the object itself.  The following gives green tests!

```
var sinon = require('sinon'),
    stubServerResponse = {
        writeHead: function(statusCode, headers) {},
        write: function(body){},
        end: function() {}
    };


function SendWelcomeResponse(response) {
    var body = 'Hello World!';

    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Content-Length': body.length});
    response.write(body);
    response.end();
}

describe('Using Sinon I should be able to mock the ServerResponse', function () {
    it.only('should mock correctly', function () {
        var mockServerResponse = sinon.mock(stubServerResponse);
        mockServerResponse.expects('writeHead').once();
        SendWelcomeResponse(mockServerResponse.object);
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but [nock](https://github.com/pgte/nock) is a possible alternative that is designed to mock http requests. We've successfully used it several times.

Comment: Thanks @TheReddest, I saw it in some peep's posts.  I'd rather not have to add yet another dependency on the tech stack.  Also, I'd just like to know what I'm doing wrong.  The instructions make it look so simple!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `sinon.mock` only stubs methods that are `hasOwnProperty` of the object you are passing it;

https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/blob/master/lib/sinon/extend.js#L63

I'm thinking `ServerResponse.writeHead` is implemented on prototype. So that its methods are not directly mocked.

An option is to create a mock object that implements `writeHead`, `write` and `end`, spy on those methods and make assertions on it.  This would be a much more manual process in creating the mocked object...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a dummy object that mimics `ServerResponse` behaviour instead of a proper `ServerResponse` (because they are not so easy to construct).

Also, you should mock a method of an object, not an entire object. And pass the object to the method, not the mock.

```
describe('Using Sinon I should be able to mock the ServerResponse', function () {
    it.only('should mock correctly', function () {
        serverResponse = {
            writeHead: function () {
            },
            write: function () {
            },
            end: function () {
            }
        }
        var mockServerResponse = sinon.mock(serverResponse, 'writeHead');
        mockServerResponse.expects('writeHead').once();
        SendWelcomeResponse(serverResponse);
    });
});
```